# menu responsivo com jQuery e css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Galera montei um menu que aparece ao colocar o cursor sobre a letra B.

O problema e que quando ele esta alinhado a esquerda o menu some no canto da página.

Se eu remover a linha (margin: 0px 0 0 -225px;) O problema e resolvido, porem se eu alinha o menu a direita o problema volta.

Tem alguma forma do jQuery fazer isso de forma automática?

Segue o menu pronto:

```css
.menu2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  height: 25px;
}

.link2 {
  margin: 0px 0 0 -225px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  width: 260px;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
}

.sub_menu2_inicio {
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.sub_menu2 {
  padding: 10px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #484848;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.sub_menu2_fim {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.sub_menu2:hover {
  background: #1E90FF;
}

.menu2:hover ul {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}

.sub_menu_seta {
  padding: 10px 8px;
}

.sub_menu_seta::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 225px;
  right: 0;
  top: 7px;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #484848;
  border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<li class="menu2">

  <i>B</i>

  <ul class="link2">
    <div class='sub_menu_seta'></div>

    <li class='sub_menu2 sub_menu2_inicio'>Sobre</li>

    <li class='sub_menu2 sub_menu2_fim'><b>Feedback</b></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Suas perguntas estão difíceis de entender. Palavras trocadas, falta de concordância. Assim fica difícil de entender e te ajudar. Sugiro que você explique melhor, releia sua pergunta devagar e veja se você mesmo a entende. É uma sugestão. Agora, tem uma propriedade CSS aí no seu código que está deixando seu menu escondido. **margin: 0px 0 0 -225px;** É esse -225px.

Comment: Bom desculpa, escrevi a pergunte muito rápido. Vou tentar explicar melhor. Se eu remover a linha (margin: 0px 0 0 -225px;) o menu funciona, o problema e que quando ele ficar alinhado a direita da tela, ele vou a esconder. O que eu estava em mente era fazer o jQuery verificar se o menu esta no meio da dela e ajudar a linha (margin: 0px 0 0 -225px;) automáticamente.

Comment: Voce esta fazendo algum tipo de menu responsivo para quando a tela for menor o menu ir para a direita?

Comment: isso mesmo amigo, sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou usar @media queries?

Comment: não tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Esse menu esta muito seco, apenas uma letra no canto da tela para acessar o menu, vai ser assim mesmo?

Comment: não isso é so um exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui pensar em um exemplo usando o a propriedade `.offset()` do jquery, segue o exemplo:

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".menu2").onMouseEnter(teste(this));
});

function teste(el) { // Sou péssimo em nomear funções então sempre deixo teste()

largTela = $(window).width();
telaMeio = largTela / 2; // Divide o tamanho da tela por dois

posElemento = $(el).offset().left();

if(posElemento > telaMeio) {
 $(el).find(".link2").addClass("direita");
}
else {
 $(el).find(".link2").addClass("esquerda");
}

}

Quando passar o mouse no elemento com a classe `.menu2` ele vai chamar a função `teste()` que calcula o tamanho da tela dividido por dois, e verifica se o elemento filho de `.menu2` com a classe `.link2` está posicionado a esquerda maior que a metade da tela.
Se estiver, adiciona a classe `.direita` senão a classe `.esquerda`.
No css a unica coisa que muda é que ao invés de você colocar a posição do sub-menu na classe `.link2` você coloca nas classes `.direita` e `.esquerda`. Por exemplo:

```
.direita {
 ... css para quando o menu estiver na direita
}
.esquerda {
 ... css para quando o menu estiver na esquerda
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Com media queries ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
... Seu estilo normal
.link2 {
  margin: 0px 0 0 0; // Para se ajustar quando o menu estiver na esquerda
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  width: 260px;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .link2 {
   margin: 0px 0 0 0 -225px !important;
 }
}
```

Nesse codigo quando a tela for menor que 800px(supondo que a partir desse tamanho de tela ou menor seu menu ficará a direta) o menu vai para -225px a esquerda ficando ajustado com o menu que agora ficara na direita.

Comment: tentei dessa forma mais não deu certo. olhas so como ficou: https://jsfiddle.net/8ae7ty4c/1/  Onde estão as letras a ele deveria mudar de lado o menu.

Comment: kkk desculpe mas acho que você se expressou errado quando me disse que queria fazer um menu responsivo. De uma olhada nesse meu projeto http://www.engatevolpato.com.br/novo/ . Quando voce redimensiona a tela do navegador e os itens do menu começam a se apertar eles se adaptam ao tamanho da tela virando aquele botao 'hamburger' como é conhecido para não ficarem sobrepostos com a logo em telas menores. Isso que é menu responsivo, já o que você está tentando fazer eu ainda não tenho um nome kk.

Comment: Por acaso o que seria todos essses menus e sub-menus?

Comment: isso e um exemplo que usei, mas vai ser assim: https://jsfiddle.net/8ae7ty4c/3/ sendo que (cadastros, produtos,pedidos) iram ficar alinhado a esquerda, e configuração ira ficar alinhado a direita.  Entendeu?

Answer (score 0):

Então use um css separado somente naquele menu:

```
css:
...
.link2 {... Seu estilo normal aqui}
```

.link2.direita {
  margin-left: -260px;
}

.direita .sub_menu_seta::after {
  left:280px;
}

E é só adicionar a classe direita na ul das configurações class="link2 direita"

Comment: sim eu pensei nesta solução, porem queria fazer o jQuery mudar o estilo de acordo com a posição do menu. Por exemplo se eu tiver vários menus. Se o menu passar do meio de tela o jQuery muda o css entendeu.